# Blank white pages after moving index.php

Tags: error

I was developing a site on my server. Craft was living at `~/mysite.com/craft/`, the webroot was `~/mysite.com/www/`, and the URL was `dev.mysite.com`.

Now I want to deploy the site to `www.mysite.com`, but the host (HostGator) requires that the hosting account's primary domain (`www.mysite.com`) point to `~/public_html/`. Ok, fine. First, I changed the `dev` subdomain to point to `~/public_html/` instead of to `~/mysite.com/www/`. Then I moved the `index.php` and `.htaccess` from `~/mysite.com/www/` to `~/public_html/` and updated the `$craftPath` variable to point to the proper directory, but now all I get is blank white pages, both on the frontend and the admin.

I deleted everything under the `craft/storage/runtime/cache/` and `craft/storage/runtime/logs/` directories, opened up an incognito Chrome window, and pointed it at `dev.mysite.com/admin` (which is now pointing and `.htaccess`-requesting `~/public_html/index.php?p=admin`, I believe...). I get redirected to `dev.mysite.com/admin/login`, but still end up with only a blank white page there.

The only `[error]` appearing in the log file is related to `testPathInfo`:

`2016/06/08 21:52:06 [error] [application] Unable to determine if PATH_INFO is enabled on the server: [curl] 6: Couldn't resolve host 'dev.mysite.com' [url] http://dev.mysite.com/index.php/testPathInfo`

Halp?

Comment: If you enable [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), do you get an error message instead of a blank, white page?

Comment: This _is_ with devMode... :-/

Comment: If you can't get it sorted and want to send some credentials over to support@craftcms.com, we can take a stab at it from there and update here with any resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure the underlying cause, but clearing the `craft/storage/runtime/cache` folder that both sites shared caused both sites to start working as expected.

Comment: Your folder clearing skills are clearly superior to mine. ;) Thanks, Brad!

Comment: I've got a college degree in clearing folders!